# searching a html file line by line for a string

Tags: python-3.x

So i have a html file, i am reading in the first four lines of the file and comparing them them to the string "<\html> ". For some reason the program wont find the string. (there is no "\" is the string being searched)

Ive tried saving each line as a string and then comparing it to the string being searched for, this still did not work.

```
def search():
    with open('cate.html') as ht:
        for cnt, line in enumerate(ht):
            if line is '<html>':
                print("found")
```

When html is found the program should just print found.
The first four lines of the html file are:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Also i have tried printing each line of the html document using print(line) and this worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `break` statement should be inside `if line is '<html>':`, so that the `for` loop is only broken when there's a match.
- Lines in the file include line breaks (and may include white-spaces). Use `line.strip()` to remove trailing characters.
- The `is` operator does not not test whether two variables have the same value, but whether they point to the same object. Use `==` to compare values.

Working implementation:

```
def search():
  with open('cate.html') as ht:
    for cnt, line in enumerate(ht):
      print(line.strip())
      if cnt < 4:
        if line.strip() == '<html>':
          print("found")
          break
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
found
```